# How to get reference to a new window of diff origin that is opened from current one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cross-domain

This is an Angular project. On my page A, I have a link that links to a page of a different origin, HTML as below:

```
...
<a href="https://another.origin"> PAGE B </a>
...
```

A user opened page B into a new window from page A. At this moment, A is still opened.

Now I want to post a message to B, like this `referenceOfB.postmessage(msg, bOrigin)` So I need to get a reference to B.

I tried 
`window.open` to get a reference to B but get null, not sure if this is the right way to approach it. Can anyone give some hints about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open` to spawn a new window - this function returns a reference to the spawned window. You can then post a message to is using 
 `postmessage`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

```
var w = window.open('https://google.com')
w.postMessage('hello', "*"); // can use target domain instead of *
```

Comment: How about if I want to refer to the new window that is opened by a user but not by my `window.open` method?

Comment: by a user on your site? You have to intercept his perceived link click and use window.open instead, I would think.